# online tool for css to scss convertor

Tags: css, sass

Is there any tool for CSS to SCSS conversion?

Comment: a CSS code is already a SCSS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you decide to converter online convert i could recommend http://beautifytools.com/css-to-scss-converter.php

you can install this package  `CSS-to-SCSS` if you have nodejs on your machine

```
npm install -g css-to-scss
```

then run this command on your command line

```
css-to-scss -o <filename>
```

Comment: It's working as expected. Thank you so much... 